# startActivityForResult with singleTop launch mode doesn't work properly on Android 9

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Activity and fragment which is settled through [jetpack navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation.html).

One of my activity has `launchMode` set to `singleTop` in AndroidManifest.xml file.

When I use `startActivity` method in my fragment it works as expected no any new Activity creating if there already is an Activity instance with the same type at the top of stack in the caller Task.

But if use `startActivityForResult` then new Activity instances keep creating even if it's already on the top of back stack.

This issue I facing on latest Android 9 version. I tested my code on older versions of Android (4.1) and `singleTop` launch mode works as expected.

What is interesting if I set programatically launch mode with this code:

```
val intent = Intent(context, T::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

`singleTop` launch mode with `startActivityForResult` start to work properly on Android 9 without any issue.

Then why it doesn't work from AndroidManifest.xml? What I missed?

Comment: I am also facing the Same Issue. Please post If you find any Solution for this.

Comment: For now I just use programmatic approach

Comment: Can you post your answer. so that I will also get some idea.

Comment: @raj it's already posted above in the question itself'